# Laravel-Mix + BrowserSync Not Loading at localhost:3000

Tags: laravel, webpack, webpack-dev-server, browser-sync, laravel-mix

I'm trying to set up `BrowserSync` to work with my `Laravel` project. However, when I run `npm run watch`, `localhost:3000` doesn't load. I'm not getting any compilation errors in the terminal. Interestingly enough, the UI dashboard on `localhost:3001` works perfectly fine.

If I run `php artisan serve`, `localhost:8000` loads up fine, but of course, it's not connected with `BrowserSync`.

My `webpack.mix.js` file looks like this:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.browserSync({proxy:'localhost:3000'});
```

I'm using the following versions:

`Laravel-Mix`: 4.0.7

`browser-sync`: 2.26.7

`webpack-dev-server`: 3.8.0

`browser-sync-webpack-plugin`: 2.0.1

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Install these two plugins:

1. "browser-sync": "^2.26.5"
2. "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",

`mix.browserSync('http://localhost:8000/');`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this modification and it still didn't work. When I run `npm run dev`, it still can't find `localhost:3000` or `localhost:8000`. If I run `php artisan serve`, it will show `localhost:8000`, but it is not synced with `browser-sync`, so it doesn't automatically refresh.

Comment: you have to run both commend together. first run (php artisan serve) it will open a server with port 8000 then run (npm run watch)

Comment: I'll try that now. Will the browser refresh in `localhost:8000`?

Comment: you saved my life @jualahmed!! spent two hours looking for a solution and this worked!!! dont know why but it worked! haha

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Saved me so much time.

Comment: Oh my god for me, the key was in the last forward slash. `proxy: 'https://mydomain.loc'` didn't work. `proxy: 'https://mydomain.loc/'` did work!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reload via brosersync adding `injectChanges: false` to my browsersync line.

[image: browsersync documentation]

Answer (score 2):

you must do it like so:

```
mix.browserSync({
    proxy: "http://localhost:8000"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you start the Laravel server via `php artisan serve`, this will be printed in the terminal:

> Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000

After starting the Laravel server, I changed the code in the webpack.mix.js file from this:

```
mix.browserSync();
```

To that:

```
mix.browserSync({
    proxy: "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[The BrowserSync docs](https://browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-ui) states that you can set `ui: false`

This way you can then set the `port: 8080` or whatever value you want that's not being used. Here's how implement it.

```js
if (!mix.inProduction()) return mix.browserSync({
  hot: true,
  ui: false,
  open: true,
  watch: true,
  https: false,
  files: [
    './app/*',
    './routes/*',
    './public/*',
    './storage/*',
    './stories/*',
    './resources/*'
  ],
  port: 8080,
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  proxy: {
    target: "http://yourlocal.dev",
    ws: true
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In your webpack.mix.js, add the following:

  mix.browserSync({
        proxy: "http://localhost:8000"
    });

After that, run the following commands

**npm uninstall browser-sync-webpack-plugin**
**npm install browser-sync-webpack-plugin**

The above will automatically open **http://localhost:3000/** on your browser
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this script before  Tag:

```
document.write("<script async src='/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js?v=2.27.7'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname));
```

If not work change your webpack.mix.js like this and the the above script before </ body> Tag:

```html
const mix = require("laravel-mix");

//Compiling scss to css
mix.sass("public/assets/css/style.scss", "public/assets/css/style.css");

mix.browserSync({
    proxy: "http://localhost/myapp/", //Your host
    files: [ //Files for watching
        "./app/**/*",
        "./routes/**/*",
        "./public/assets/css/*.css",
        "./public/js/*.js",
        "./resources/views/**/*.blade.php",
        "./resources/lang/**/*",
    ],
});
```

Then run: npm run watch